# Wagtail SteamFields for community user generated content instead of editor, author workflow

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I really like StreamFields, but I don't want the baggage of Wagtail's Publishing system.

For example, consider a Forum community site. Instead of using CK Editor or BBCode, Markdown etc form input. I want to give users the option of StreamField based input to construct posts or replies

Is this possible? If yes, what steps would I need to take or edits to Wagtail do I need to do?

I'm guessing using a permission system while keeping the user as a limited admin would be the thing to do, since removing the user from admin doesn't seem to be possible since Wagtail is heavily reliant on Django Admin.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing using a permission system while keeping the user as a
> limited admin would be the thing to do, since removing the user from
> admin doesn't seem to be possible since Wagtail is heavily reliant on
> Django Admin.

If you want to reuse StreamFields, you probably want to use the Wagtail admin interface; doing otherwise is likely to be quite a bit of work. So users will need to be able to log in and have the `wagtail_admin` permission so they can access the admin interface. If you tried to use Page models for your forum, you are going to end up crossways of the way [Wagtail's page permissions cascade](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/permissions.html). You could probably [write your own admin views](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/extending/admin_views.html) for regular users to add certain kinds of content.

But honestly, unless you have quite a bit of experience with Wagtail in its normal content management mode, I wouldn't suggest you try using it for this use case.